# Python to R translation

Tags: r, algorithm, for-loop

I want to implement the Ising model in R :

My attempt is :

```
L=4
N=L*L;N
A= matrix(nr= N, nc=L, 0);A
for (i in 0:N-1){
  A[i+1,1] = (i %/% L) * L + (i + 1) %% L
  A[i+1,2] = (i + L) %% N
  A[i+1,3] = (i %/% L) * L + (i - 1) %% L
  A[i+1,4] = (i - L) %% N
}

Temperature = 100
Spin = sample(c(1,-1),N,replace=TRUE)
spin_table = matrix(NA,L,L);spin_table
nsteps = 100 *L*L
for(step in 1:nsteps){
  for(n in A){
    k = sample(1,N-1,replace=TRUE)
    delta_E = 2.0 * Spin[k] * sum(Spin[n])
    if(runif(1) < exp(-delta_E/Temperature)){
      Spin[k] = Spin[k]*-1
    }
    }}
  

for(k in 1:N-1){
  y = k %/% L
  x = k %% L
  spin_table[x,y] = Spin[k]}
spin_table
```

But I have several problems implement it.I have mess up R code with some pseudocode. Can someone help me out with this ?

I want the resulting plot to be with ggplot with scale_fill_viridis(option="D").
Any help ?

**Python**

in Python this model is :

```
L = 64
N = L*L

#   // floor division
#   %  modulus
neighbors = {i : ((i // L) * L + (i + 1) % L,   # RIGHT
                 (i + L) % N,                   # DOWN
                 (i // L) * L + (i - 1) % L,    # LEFT
                 (i - L) % N)                   # UP
                 for i in range(N)}

Temperature = 1.0
Spin = [np.random.choice([1, -1]) for k in range(N)]
spin_table = [[None for x in range(L)] for y in range(L)]

nsteps = N * 100
for step in range(nsteps):
    k = np.random.randint(0, N - 1)
    delta_E = 2 * Spin[k] * sum(Spin[n] for n in neighbors[k])
    if np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) < np.exp(-delta_E/Temperature):
        Spin[k] *= +1

for k in range(N):
    y = k // L
    x = k % L
    spin_table[x][y] = Spin[k]

pylab.close()
pylab.imshow(spin_table,extent=[0,L,0,L],interpolation='nearest')
pylab.title("Temperature: "+str(Temperature)+", Grid Size: "+str(L))
pylab.show()
```

Comment: `0:N-1` should be `1 : N - 1` or `0 : (N - 1)` (but neither is good; instead, forget about the existence of the error-prone `:` operator and use `seq()` instead).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I would appreciate any help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in

```
if(runif(1) < exp(-delta_E/Temperature))
```

The `if` condition is a logical vector of length `N`. This is ambiguous, since you might mean that *all* vector elements should be `TRUE` or *any* element should be `TRUE`. Depending on what applies, you have to write:

```
if(all(runif(1) < exp(-delta_E/Temperature)))
```

or

```
if(any(runif(1) < exp(-delta_E/Temperature)))
```

Assuming the former, you can write:

```
L=4
N=L*L;N
A= matrix(nr= N, nc=L, 0);A
for (i in 0:N-1){
  A[i+1,1] = (i %/% L) * L + (i + 1) %% L
  A[i+1,2] = (i + L) %% N
  A[i+1,3] = (i %/% L) * L + (i - 1) %% L
  A[i+1,4] = (i - L) %% N
}
 
Temperature = 100
Spin = sample(c(1,-1),N,replace=TRUE)
spin_table = matrix(NA,L,L);spin_table
nsteps = 100 *L*L
for(step in 1:nsteps){
  for(n in A){
    k = sample(1,N-1,replace=TRUE)
    delta_E = 2.0 * Spin[k] * sum(Spin[n])
    if(all(runif(1) < exp(-delta_E/Temperature))){
      Spin[k] = Spin[k]*-1
    }
  }
}
  
 
for(k in 1:N-1){
  y = k %/% L
  x = k %% L
  spin_table[x,y] = Spin[k]}
spin_table
```

The code does not break now. Whether this is a correct implementation of your model is another story.

P.S. If you are new to R, it might be worth noting that

```
0:N-1
```

is equivalent to

```
(0:N)-1
```

and not

```
0:(N-1)
```

As a second note, in R, array indices are not zero-based.

If `v` is a vector, the assignment

```
v[0] <- 100
```

writes in a sort of empty location, which leaves `v` unchanged, but you do not get any error (`<-` is the stylistically correct way to make assignments).